# React Native save state even after app exits

Tags: react-native

How do I save text input state?
I'm using <TextInput> and when user enter value the <Text> component contains that input (by React.useState())

But when I exit app the <Text> component contains default value.

How can I save the input even when the apps exits. And then it will show to state before closing.

Thank you.

I've tried overiting JSON file, using state, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hey, you should do a complete research on React Native topics and study about persistent storage concepts like Async Storage, DBs, etc. Please ask questions after prior research.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to persist after the app is closed, the data should be saved to a storage, for example [async storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage), and then retrieved later when you open the app again.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to do one of these:

1. create  an async storage: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/
2. use a state management system like redux which will save the states in a store for you
3. write the data to a database like firebase and then retrieve it to display it